# Multiple Raphael.js/eve.js charts on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I seem to have gotten it to work, kind of. But I can't get both numbers to increment, only the second one does (or the first one if there is no second).

I'd like both "XX%" numbers to animate, but can't figure out what I've done wrong

Here's the [relevant fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/demchak_alex/GGSpX/) showing what I have, that are using elements like this

```
<div id="canvas"> </div>

<div id="canvas2"> </div>
```

EDIT: forgot to mention that the numbers aren't quite right with 2 charts on a page

Comment: error in consoles says eve.js isn't available.  looks like you're linking to github for that. is there not a version of eve.js available on cloudflare?

Comment: there is: //cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/eve.js/0.8.4/eve.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `onAnimate` function exists twice... Rename one of them (or both), and everything works fine :)

http://jsfiddle.net/GGSpX/1/

Comment: oh wow, I've got a case of the (almost) fridays >.<

Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: I know that feeling, bro :)